# Python Selenium - using selenium's webdriver manager with proxy server

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, proxy

I want to use selenium's webdriver manager, the one that was introduced in 4.6.0, with only selenium needed to be installed, in python, but while, it's trying to get a version of webdriver I would like to be connected to some proxy server with HTTP protocol. I would like to do it for both - Chrome and Edge.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=optionsChrome) #this will run #selenium's webdriver manager to get proper webdriver version.
driver = webdriver.Edge(options=optionsEdge)
```

I tried to do it through browser options, (as chat gpt instructed...), but that doesn't work and it doesn't have any further suggestions.

```
optionsEdge = EdgeOptions()
optionsEdge.add_argument('--proxy-server={}'.format(proxy_url))
```

```
optionsChrome = ChromeOptions()
optionsChrome.add_argument('--proxy-server={}'.format(proxy_url))
```

proxy_url is properly formatted i checked, like: proxy_url
= "http://example.com:8080"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if OP still needs an answer, but I can share the way how I was able to handle a similar case.

So I wasn't able to download the driver due to a corporate proxy, and the solution was to use a custom HTTP client and requests lib. Here is an example for Chrome:

```
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.core.download_manager import WDMDownloadManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.core.http import HttpClient
from requests import Response

class CustomHttpClient(HttpClient):

def get(self, url, params=None, **kwargs) -> Response:
    proxies = {
        'http': 'http://some-proxy:80',
        'https': 'http://some-proxy:80',
    }
    return requests.get(url, params, proxies=proxies, **kwargs)

download_manager = WDMDownloadManager(CustomHttpClient())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager(download_manager=download_manager).install()))
```